# DB structure for Twitter home/Facebook wall?

Tags: mysql, feed, facebook-wall

Basically a live feed of all your friends' recent posts.

In a stupid sort of approach I think I'd start by building a query like:

`SELECT * FROM tblposts WHERE userid=`friend_id_1`OR userid=`friend_id_2`......` and so on

Where friend_id_% is the userid of a friend from your friends list. But this must be a very inefficient way of doing it, right? Is there any faster way of doing this in MySQL? Maybe some clever DB schema?

(I know FB uses Hadoob but I'm not experienced enough to go that far :( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of IDs that you want to query then you should use IN:

```
SELECT * FROM tblposts WHERE userid IN (friend_id_1, friend_id_2, ...)
```

But in this case I think you can use a join instead.

```
SELECT * FROM tblposts AS T1
JOIN (
   SELECT friendid             -- I just made up this query.
   FROM friends                -- You need to replace it with the
   WHERE userid = 'youruserid' -- real query to get someone's friends.
) AS T2
ON T1.userid = T2.friendid
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. Would it be something drastically different from what a big popular site like Twitter might do?

Comment: @mathon12: A large site would certainly not do exactly this. For a start, some users might have 1000s of friends and they may have posted 1000s of messages each, so you would need some paging mechanism, plus sorting, filtering, etc... Currently this query could return millions of rows in no particular order.

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be the case. One 'hack' around this might be to limit the result to first 50-100 matches sorted by time because only the recent posts are ever usually shown. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump, but I think the query above implies that the `friends` table has a lot of redundant records? (x is friends with y, y is friends with x; 2 records?)

If `friends` table has fields `sender_id` `receiver_id` and `request_status` instead, can the query above be modified in a way that it returns friends list against `youruserid`, i.e. select value of receiver_id if sender_id==youruserid and vice versa so we get one list of all friends of `youruserid`? I can't think of a better table to avoid duplication.